# cocos2D CCLayer or CCLayerColor setOpacity

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, opacity, layer

I'm trying to animate the opacity of a CCLayerColor and its not working. Here are my efforts so far. I've defined retryMenuLayer in .h like

```
CCLayerColor *retryMenuLayer;
```

and in .m file

```
retryMenuLayer = [CCLayerColor node];
[self addChild:retryMenuLayer z:5];

retryMenuLayer.scale = 0.5;
[retryMenuLayer setOpacity:0];
```

and in appearing method, I'm calling this.

```
[retryMenuLayer runAction:[CCFadeIn actionWithDuration:1]];

//OR

[retryMenuLayer setOpacity:255];
```

What happens is the background of retryMenuLayer animates from transparent to solid black but the contents inside (its children - a Menu with buttons) doesn't animate. In fact I have to use visibility property to at least disappear until the method is called.

```
retryMenuLayer.visible = NO; // When initiating.
retryMenuLayer.visible = YES; // When need to appear the layer.
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen? What is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For transparency in `CCLayerColor`, I use

```
    CCLayerColor *_shadowLayer = [CCLayerColor layerWithColor: ccc4(0,0,0, 100)];
```

for a transparent black color.

To make it `FadeIn`, this should work:

```
CCLayerColor _shadowLayer = [CCLayerColor layerWithColor: ccc4(0,0,0, 0)];
[_shadowLayer setContentSize: CGSizeMake(_winSize.width, _winSize.height)];
_shadowLayer.anchorPoint = ccp(0.0f, 0.0f); 
_shadowLayer.position = ccp(0, 0);

[self addChild: _shadowLayer];

[_shadowLayer runAction: [CCFadeTo actionWithDuration:1.5f opacity:100]];
```

Note here that I added the shadow layer to `self`, that is my own customized layer. If I would add it to a sprite that is faded in, the opacity does not pull through to the shadow layer. There seems to be a workaround on that by user "aerostat" in [the link in qklxtlx's answer](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/5088), though.

Answer (score 3):

CCLayer doesn't have opacity. Please refer to this http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/5088